# Running multiple testcases (TestNG cases) in a single browser using maven build tool?

Tags: testing, maven, automation, testng

I am new to testing and I was given on automating a registration page. I need to validate each field in separate test-case. If I am validating first-name, all other fields need to be of valid values and that goes on for other fields validation. I have nearly 10 test-cases (10 @Test methods) and each test-case is opening in a new browser and it is very odd to show the results as a demo automation. Is there any way so that I can run all the test-cases in a single browser. any examples would be of great help.. Thanks in advance. - Dev

Answer (score 0):

The question is: Where do you open your browser? I assume in @BeforeMethod ? The best solution is to put the setup (selenium ?) into the @BeforeSuite method which can be defined in a base class for all Test classes.